# Can I use the name of a fictional company

Tags: copyright, trademark, name, trade-name

How could I possibly know if I can use the name 'LexCorp' for a real company. LexCorp is the company of Lex Luthor in the comic books of DC.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LexCorp

Answer (score 2):

You can check the [USPTO trademark database](http://tmsearch.uspto.gov/bin/gate.exe?f=searchss&state=4810:5rami.1.1), to see if it is a registered trademark. You could also ask [LexCorp](https://www.lexcorp.io/#/about) about their claim that it is a registered trademark of DC comics or WB, though their CEO appears to be a criminal mastermind and might not tell the truth. There is some unclarity as to the latter point (criminality). USPTO includes a "don't rely on the database" disclaimer, so maybe it is registered and it just doesn't show up

Answer (score 1):

LexiCorp was registered then abandoned. See details below.
[image]
https://huski.ai/trademark/78509802

The reason of giving up this trademark was not clear.

Comment: LexCorp, or LexiCorp?

Comment: Given  that LexCorp in real life has a Spanish language description for a law firm in the advertisement displayed, it seems likely that the person using it didn't know of its comic book connotations originally and eventually found those connotations to be a drag and found another name.